# How can I integrate AWS RDS with the AWS Elasticsearch service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-elasticsearch

How do I integrate AWS RDS with the AWS Elasticsearch service? Is there any AWS service so that I can use it to stream data from AWS RDS to AWS Elasticsearch for Indexing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a magic way like [this for DynamoDB.](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb)

I can think of three ways.

1. set up your RDS to log all transactions, and set up a logstash to parse any inserts and updates and insert to ES.
2. Create a special log file, that your app uses to store the inserts and updates.  Less work to set up logstash this way.
3. Make your app send all inserts and updates through SNS.  From there, distribute them to a ES SQS queue and a RDS SQS queue, and have workers (or lambdas) for each queue to do the inserts to their respective stores.